# Estimate $P(X\ge 4)$ using Chebyshev's inequality when $X \sim Exp(1)$

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with parameter 1. I would like to apply Chebyshev's inequality in order to estimate

$$P(X\ge 4).$$

I know Chebyshev's inequality but I do not understand how to apply it.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Chebyshev inequality but I don't know the mean and standard deviation of exponential also don't know how to find this for exponential.

Comment: @Atul well... compute them! Or look them up on wikipedia, or your book, or your notes, or...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Chebyshev's inequality says

$$P(|X-E(X)|\ge c)\le c^{-2} \mathrm{Var}(X).$$

Since $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter 1, we have

$$ \mathrm{Var}(X)=E(X)=1,$$

so

$$P(|X-1|\ge c)\le c^{-2}.$$

Now choose $c$ suitably in order to get a bound for $P(X\ge 4)$.

Comment: I think c is here 3 because 4-1=3  I don't know I'm wrong or right

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure if you have the right argument in mind. Since $X$ is non-negative anyway, you have $|X-1|\ge3$ if and only if $X\ge 4$. Do you follow?

Comment: the answer of this question is 0.111111111

Comment: Yes, this approach yields the bound $1/9=0,\bar{1}$. If this helped you and your problem is solved, you can accept my answer.